# ORACLE vs SQL Server from text data type point of view

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sqldatatypes, type-conversion

These days I am facing a problem related to text datatype differences between Oracle and SQL Server.
More exactly I am comparing a concatenation of chars from Oracle with a `varchar` column from SQL Server.

Here is the condition:

```
rtrim(NUM1) || ' ' || rtrim(NUM2) <> D2.NUM
```

and it is launched from Oracle.

Where NUM1 & NUM2 are `varchar2` data type from Oracle while NUM is `varchar` in SQL Server.

I want that the condition to be false but, unfortunately it is true.

Normally, both variables have same value = '7 a' but they are not recognized as being the same.

I was trying to manually do a hardcoded comparison, meaning `'7 a' <> D2.NUM` which is false, because Oracle considers the values to be the same but when I am comparing `rtrim(NUM1) || ' ' || rtrim(NUM2)` with '7 a', Oracle consider them as different.

Does anyone have any idea why Oracle consider that `rtrim(NUM1) || ' ' || rtrim(NUM2) <> '7 a'` is true?

Comment: I don't really understand your question but could it be that `D2.NUM` is null? Maybe `'7 a' <> D2.NUM` is false because it's null and not because *Oracle consider that they are the same value*

Comment: D2.NUM is not null. the question is: why Oracle consider that '7 a' is different than '7 a', where 1st '7 a' is comming form rtrim(NUM1) || ' ' || rtrim(NUM2) (Oracle varchar2 value) while the 2nd '7 a' id comming from D2.NUM (MS-SQL varchar value).

Comment: After rereading your question for the 4th time, I still don't understand what you're asking... if `'7 a' <> D2.NUM` is false then either d2.num is null (which according to your comment isn't) or it's '7 a'. If `rtrim(NUM1) || ' ' || rtrim(NUM2) <> '7 a'` which is (if d2.num is not null) the same as `rtrim(NUM1) || ' ' || rtrim(NUM2) <> D2.NUM` is true, then why do you expect it to be false ?

Comment: Sorry if I am not so clear in my explanations. 
In Oracle, the rtrim(NUM1) || ' ' || rtrim(NUM2) results into '7 a'. 
In MS-SQL, D2.NUm is also '7 a'. 
Comparing these 2 values results that they are different. 
My question is " why Oracle consider they are different?" since both of them look to have same value?

Comment: Why do you think it's an Oracle-ms sql thing? you wrote that `rtrim(NUM1) || ' ' || rtrim(NUM2) <> '7 a'` . Try `select dump(rtrim(NUM1) || ' ' || rtrim(NUM2)) from....` and see what you really have there

Comment: Indeed, I was splitting the comparison in rtrim(NUM1) || ' ' || rtrim(NUM2) <> '7 a' and '7 a' <> D2.NUM and the 1st one is true while '7 a' <> D2.NUm is false. So, the problem is from Oracle because rtrim(NUM1) || ' ' || rtrim(NUM2) <> '7 a' returns true even if dump (rtrim(NUM1) || ' ' || rtrim(NUM2)) returns Typ=1 Len=3: 55,32,97

Comment: Now that's wierd... maybe you ought to close this question and reopen a new one. BTW what do get for `dump('7 a')` ? and what happens if you try `rtrim(NUM1) || ' ' || rtrim(NUM2) <> trim('7 a')` ?

Comment: dump('7 a') = Typ=96 Len=3: 55,32,97 / rtrim(NUM1) || ' ' || rtrim(NUM2) <> trim('7 a') is true. I don't know if  it counts that Typ = 96 is different than Typ = 1...

Comment: No, oracle knows to implicitly convert typ=1 (varchar2) to typ=96 (char)... I think it's better for you to close this question and ask a new one with the "exact" problem. The way things are right now - nobody will read all these comments to understand what's going on...

Comment: Hello everybody,
 
I managed to get a solution for my problem using another table where were inserted all selected data from my sentence + an extra field which contains the concatenation 
`rtrim(NUM1) || ' ' || rtrim(NUM2)`
 
After that, I compared just 2 simple fields and the values were identically (as they should have been from the begining).
 
Thank you all who had a look over my problem.

Comment: Great! add this as an answer and accept it as soon as you can. BTW it could be a good thing to add the exact version of your ORACLE DB.